# Serial Port Unauthorized Exception

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to access RFID Reader through Arduino application which gives me the right output on control monitor.

But when I tried to access it through visual studio C#, it works only once and then gives me access is denied! And also stopped working on Arduino IDE.

```
//Function  to initialize serial port

SerialPort RFIDPort    
public SerialPort initializeRFIDPort()
{
    try
    {
        RFIDPort = new SerialPort("COM4",9600,Parity.None,8, StopBits.One);

        if (RFIDPort.IsOpen)
            RFIDPort.Close();

        if(!RFIDPort.IsOpen)
            RFIDPort.Open();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {MessageBox.Show( ex.Message); }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        RFIDPort = null;
    }

    return RFIDPort;
}
```

I put the function here:

```
public products()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initializeRFIDPort();
}
```

There is two scan button the first one for scanning and then add data to the database and the second button is to scan and search for data

```
private void ScanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        scanButtonIsClicked = true;

        if (RFIDPort.IsOpen)
        {
            RFIDPort.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("RFID Reader is not connected!");
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again");
    }
}

private void Searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scansearchbtn = true;
    scanButtonIsClicked = false;

    try
    {
        if (RFIDPort.IsOpen)
        {
             RFIDPort.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;

            textBox2.Text = "";

        }
        else 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("RFID Reader is not connected!"); 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Please reconnect your device ");
    }
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string line = RFIDPort.ReadLine();

        if (scanButtonIsClicked == true)
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line);
        else
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(Line2Received), line);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException) { }
    catch (Exception){ MessageBox.Show("Can't Read from RFID Device.Please try again"); }
}

private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

private void LineReceived(string line)
{
    textBox2.Text = line;
}
private void Line2Received(string line)
{
    textBox1.Text = line;
}
```

And then I closed serial port in Forum-Closing.
Please if anyone can lead me to the right way. I have try many times and it works randomly!
On Aruino side this is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Instance of the class

 MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key; 

// Init array that will store new NUID 
  byte nuidPICC[10];

  void setup() 
 { 
 Serial.begin(9600);
 SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
 rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 
 for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
 {
  key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
 }
 printHex(key.keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
 Serial.println();
 }

 void loop() 
{

if ( ! rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
 return;
if ( ! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
 return;

 //  Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);
//  Serial.println(rfid.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

// Check is the PICC of Classic MIFARE type
if (piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI &&  piccType != 
MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K && piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_4K) 
  {
    Serial.println(F("Your tag is not of type MIFARE Classic."));
    return;
  }
 // Store NUID into nuidPICC array
 for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
 {
   nuidPICC[i] = rfid.uid.uidByte[i];
 }
 printHex(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size);
 Serial.println();
 // Halt PICC
 rfid.PICC_HaltA();
// Stop encryption on PCD
  rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
 }
 void printHex(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize)
 {
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
   Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
   Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
 }
 }
```

Comment: inside of your serialPort1_DataRecieved callback - try making your first line of code: ```RFIDPort.DataReceived -= serialPort1_DataReceived;```

Comment: Thank u it first works when I run the program for 3 times but then gives the previous error!

Comment: My guess is that after processing the line, you should try to clear the serial port's contents. It might be flooding (exceeding its limit). OR on the Arduino side, make sure that each line written replaces the last (NOT APPEND a new line).

Comment: please recheck my Arduino code. Thank u

Comment: before any of your ```Serial.println("...")``` statements my suggestion would be to issue ```Serial.flush()```. For your reference here are the [DOCS for the flush method](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/). As for the ```printHex``` loop, just be sure to issue it before the loop, not exactly before the ```Serial.print(<byte>)``` statements.

Comment: I don't understand what u said about print Hex??